# How to put local images into PDFMake in nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdfmake

I have a local image that I'm trying to display in the header, but I keep getting an error and not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
let docDefinition = {
    pageMargins: [20, 20, 20, 20],
    styles: {
        smoll: {
            fontSize: 7,
            margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
        },
    },
    header: () => {
        return {
            margin: [0, 20, 0, 0],
            alignment: "left",

            image: "./images/CP_Logo.png",
            height: 100,
        };
    },
};
```

The error I get is:

> "Invalid image: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './images/CP_Logo.png'
> Images dictionary should contain dataURL entries (or local file paths in node.js)".
> [ERROR] 15:19:01 UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "Invalid image: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './images/CP_Logo.png'
> Images dictionary should contain dataURL entries (or local file paths in node.js)".

here is the tree structure:

[image]

Comment: So uhm, can you show the tree structure of the project?

Comment: @aymcg31Apologies, I've added it in now

Comment: Is the code you showed in index.js ?

Comment: @aymcg31yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you need to convert the file to Base64 string first, since that's the only accepted format.
You can either do this in JS:

```
var fs = require('fs');

// function to encode file data to base64 encoded string
function base64_encode(file) {
    // read binary data
    var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
    // convert binary data to base64 encoded string
    return new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');
}
```

(That's one example, there's a lot of other ways)

Or, you can convert it on a website and just put the hardcoded string in place of the path you put.

EDIT: Should look like this:

```
 image: "data:image/png;base64,<base64 string of the png>",
```